# ImportError even after pip install (pyinotify)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kali-linux

```
┌──(jimmyboy㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf] 
└─$ ./mitmf.py --help
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./mitmf.py", line 29, in <module> import core.responder.settings as settings File "/home/jimmyboy/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf/core/responder/settings.py", line 24, in <module> from core.configwatcher import ConfigWatcher File "/home/jimmyboy/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf/core/configwatcher.py", line 20, in <module> import pyinotify ImportError: No module named pyinotify 

┌──(jimmyboy㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf] 
└─$ pip install pyinotify
1 ⨯ Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable Requirement already satisfied: pyinotify in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.9.6) 

┌──(jimmyboy㉿kali)-[~/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf] 
└─$ pip3 install pyinotify
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable Requirement already satisfied: pyinotify in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.9.6)
```

This is the error, it says that this is not found, and when I install it, it says that it already exists! What can I do?

Comment: Could you make sure that you are running both your program and pip with the same python version?

Comment: how can i check for it?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have different Python installations on your system and therefore packages will be installed in different locations.

Here are a few things to check, especially if you are working with virtual environments or something like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv):

- Which version is your script (`mitmf.py`) using?
  Is the first line in your script something like the following?

  ```
  #!/bin/usr/env python
  ```

  or

  ```
  #!/bin/usr/env python3
  ```
- Check your actual Python installation. On the command line run:

  ```
  $ type python
  $ which python
  ```

  and

  ```
  $ type python3
  $ which python3
  ```

  Both commands should show you the full path to the respective Python interpreter. (`type` and `which` can show different paths in certain circumstances, if that's the case, try to understand why)
- Check which `pip` you are using:

  ```
  $ pip --version
  ```

  and

  ```
  $ pip3 --version
  ```
- If the above doesn't give you a good hint, try adding these two lines to your script:

  ```python
  import sys
  print(sys.path)
  ```

  [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) is a list of paths where the current Python interpreter will search for installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip install pywhatkit` in the command terminal. Then `pywhatkit` would start working shortly.